# How can I set the default text size in Outlook 2003 for email messages?

Tags: windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook

XP Pro SP3.

Somehow I have made a change and now my signature and all text in the mail message are at 6 point Arial rather than 12 point Times New Roman.

I know I can change each message, but it used to come up in 12 Pt. TNR.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:
Tools -> Options -> Mail Format -> Stationery and Fonts
Then ensure Stationery is set to , then click the "Font..." button and the check/change the options shown.
Hopefully that will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Plus 1 and accept. When I went to the location the original choices were still there. However, I OK'd and then applied and all is good again.